# S3 connections timing out quickly in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am writing a service that will retrieve data from S3 after receiving a request.  The data is stored in .gz files.  This service will not be constantly flooded with data, meaning it could go many seconds before receiving a second request.  I'm having trouble keeping my S3 connection from resetting after a fairly small amount of time.  The issue seems to be that `boto3.client()` resets the connection much more quickly than I would like it to.

To test, I used this bit of code:

```
import boto3
import logging
import datetime
import time
import gzipinputstream

logging.basicConfig(level='DEBUG')
logging.getLogger('botocore').setLevel('INFO')

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = 'foo'
key = 'bar'

count = 0
while True:
  count += 1
  start = datetime.datetime.now()
  x = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
  y = x['Body']
  z = gzipinputstream.GzipInputStream(y)
  final_obj = z.read()
  end = datetime.datetime.now()
  print "Test #%d: started at %s, ended at %s, duration = %s" % (count,start,end,end-start)
```

When I run the above code, I see the following.  The initial request takes a bit longer than the rest, but each request from #2 onward is much faster:

```
INFO:botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): session4c.s3.amazonaws.com
Test #1: started at 2017-01-25 14:50:26.295239, ended at 2017-01-25 14:50:30.412478, duration = 0:00:04.117239
Test #2: started at 2017-01-25 14:50:30.412581, ended at 2017-01-25 14:50:30.447595, duration = 0:00:00.035014
Test #3: started at 2017-01-25 14:50:30.447655, ended at 2017-01-25 14:50:30.474377, duration = 0:00:00.026722
Test #4: started at 2017-01-25 14:50:30.474443, ended at 2017-01-25 14:50:30.499979, duration = 0:00:00.025536
Test #5: started at 2017-01-25 14:50:30.500040, ended at 2017-01-25 14:50:30.595240, duration = 0:00:00.095200
```

When I take that same code and add `time.sleep(10)` to the bottom of the loop to simulate a gap between requests, I see the following.  Each request takes roughly as long as the first due to each request reconnecting:

```
INFO:botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): session4c.s3.amazonaws.com
Test #1: started at 2017-01-25 14:50:44.916388, ended at 2017-01-25 14:50:49.315392, duration = 0:00:04.399004
INFO:botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Resetting dropped connection: session4c.s3.amazonaws.com
Test #2: started at 2017-01-25 14:50:59.325521, ended at 2017-01-25 14:51:03.726388, duration = 0:00:04.400867
INFO:botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Resetting dropped connection: session4c.s3.amazonaws.com
Test #3: started at 2017-01-25 14:51:13.736561, ended at 2017-01-25 14:51:17.273182, duration = 0:00:03.536621
INFO:botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Resetting dropped connection: session4c.s3.amazonaws.com
Test #4: started at 2017-01-25 14:51:27.282636, ended at 2017-01-25 14:51:31.682258, duration = 0:00:04.399622
INFO:botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Resetting dropped connection: session4c.s3.amazonaws.com
Test #5: started at 2017-01-25 14:51:41.692450, ended at 2017-01-25 14:51:45.225243, duration = 0:00:03.532793
```

I have searched high and low for ways to increase the timeout within the `boto3.client()` and its underlying `requests` and `urllib3` libraries but have come up empty.  I see nothing in the boto3 docs either.  Adding `use_ssl=False` to the `boto3.client()` call does help somewhat by reducing network chatter.  The reconnects occur after 20-30 seconds instead of in <10 seconds.

Is there a way to increase the amount of time an S3 connection can stay open?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.

S3 itself drops any idle Keep-Alive connections after a few seconds... as any web server will do... the "connections" to S3 are just HTTP/S connections to the S3 API endpoint.  They aren't meant to stay usable for very long.

The real question may be why the connection takes 4 seconds to establish.  That seems excessive.